# Context in an Android DatePicker

Tags: android, datepicker, this, android-context

I'm new to android and I admit I don't fully understand what context is as it applies to Android. I understand a little, but not fully. I'm trying to modify an Android Datepicker so that only the day and month are in the DatePickerDialog. I asked stackoverflow and I was given one answer in the form of three code blocks. The code is below. My problem is I'm getting one error at
`mDialog = new CustomDPDialog(getContext()`, `this`,... the error is at `getContext()`. It says that `getContext()` is undefined for the `onClickListener`. So, looking at the below code, what would be the fix for `getContext()`? Creating a `getContext()` method actually breaks the code worse. And using context, null in place of `getContext(), this,` erases the error, but it shouldn't be null, it should be `this`.

```
static final int ID_DATEPICKER = 0;
private int myYear, myMonth, myDay;
TextView dateDisplay;
Dialog mDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    dateDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);

    Button datePickerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.datepickerbutton);
    datePickerButton.setOnClickListener(datePickerButtonOnClickListener);
    }
private Button.OnClickListener datePickerButtonOnClickListener
= new Button.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        mDialog = new CustomDPDialog(getContext(), this, 
        c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
        c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); 
        mDialog.show(); 
        DatePicker dp = findDatePicker((ViewGroup) mDialog.getWindow().getDecorView()); 
        if (dp != null) { 
        ((ViewGroup) dp.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    class CustomDPDialog extends DatePickerDialog {
        public CustomDPDialog(Context context, 
                OnDateSetListener callBack, int myYear, int myMonth, 
                int myDay) {
                super(context, callBack, myYear, myMonth, myDay);
                }
        @Override 
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            super.onDateChanged(view, year, month, day);
            mDialog.setTitle((month + 1) + "-" + day + "-");
        }

    }

    private DatePicker findDatePicker(ViewGroup group) {
        if (group != null) {
            for (int i = 0, j = group.getChildCount(); i < j; i++) {
                View child = group.getChildAt(i);
                if (child instanceof DatePicker) {
                    return (DatePicker) child;
                } else if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                    DatePicker result = findDatePicker((ViewGroup) child);
                    if (result != null)
                        return result;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
v.getContext()
```

or

```
getApplicationContext()
```

I recommend the first since getApplicationContext() can sometimes cause problems

Comment: nope, neither one worked. But I see where you're going with your reasoning. I don't think v.getContext works because it doesn't want the context of the view, I think it wants the context of the DatePicker. So now I'm trying all the variables in place of v. Thaks for the help!

Comment: hmmm... I would think v.getContext() would work either way. Well let me know what did end up working!!

Comment: with all of the suggestions Eclipse says "The method getContext(View.OnClickListener) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}" I don't undertsnad what bit of code is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

`getActivity()` should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

`ActivityName.this` should work